# using ruby json library to parse json data into a hash some keys missing

Tags: ruby, json

lets say I have this json data file

```
{
  "page": {
    "title": "Example Page"
  },
  "employers": {
    "name": "Jon"
  },
  "employees": [
    { "name": "Mike", "nicknames": ["Superman"] },
    { "name": "Peter", "nicknames": ["Peet", "Peetee", "Peterr"] }
  ]
}
```

this data.json file exist as a file outside of the script

I have these 3 lines to read and parse it with json ruby library

```
data = File.read("data.json")
obj = JSON.parse(data)
puts obj.values
```

in my terminal it comes out to be like this

```
{"title"=>"Example Page"}
{"name"=>"Jon"}
{"name"=>"Mike", "nicknames"=>["Superman"]}
{"name"=>"Peter", "nicknames"=>["Peet", "Peetee", "Peterr"]}
```

what happened to employers and employees? now I have the same key or name in this case. Its difficult for me to grab the values to use them.

Comment: what data exactly do you need from this json?

Answer (score 4):

Employers and employees are the keys for primary hash, and you requested values, that's why you get what you get. Try putting obj .